# jQuery show/fadeIn Does not apply display:block to a child element inside a hidden parent element - FireFox ONLY

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox, iframe

**Problem:** FireFox Only.

On page load, I have a hidden iFrame (I do not control the parent page).  Inside this iFrame I have elements that are hidden/show based on state, and using jQuery `show()`/`fadeIn()` to handle this.

When the iFrame is hidden on page load (it always is), `display:block` or `display:inline-block` is not being applied to these elements.  If the iFrame is visible on page load, the children elements are properly handled and assigned `display:block`.

I realize I can fix this issue by simply using `$el.css('display', 'block')`, but I want to understand the source of the issue and resolve it properly, and discover if this is a jQuery bug or not.  Why is jQuery not showing elements based on their parents, and why is this *only* FireFox (Gecko rendering engine)?

**Expected Result:**
Regardless of the parent's (iFrame's) visibility or display, the children elements should be updated to a visible state when using `$el.show()` (and of course, remain hidden until the parent element is shown).

I've done some extensive searching for a solid answer, but all the forums end without a resolve or answer and use a workaround instead.

Anyone seen and/or resolved this before?

Thanks!

**Update**

As I was creating the fiddle(s) I came on to a solution.  I'm not 100% positive on what is going on behind the scenes with the iFrame, but now see a pattern.  It appears load events are not firing within the iFrame.

Parent Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kaizen5/BxkxB/

iFrame Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pQqXc/ (there is a container on this page that is made visible on load)

You'll notice that when you click the ('bad') button first that it reveals the iFrame and the fiddle appears to be empty.  This is because the Fiddle iFrame is calling a function on load that should reveal the contents of the fiddle.  This mimics the issue I am seeing in my own solution.

The 'good' button, shows the iFrame and also (re)assigns the 'src' forcing a new rendering of the page.  This time, the on load events fire just fine.

Comment: Could you provide a link to your page? Or, preferably, a link to a simplified version of it (that only shows the problem, nothing else)? Your question now contains too many unknowns... how is the iframe hidden; why should you care what its content look like if it's always hidden, etc.

Comment: I mean, I made [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ypx75/1) that simply shows it works, in all browsers, so your situation is different than that.

Comment: Hey Mr Lister, unfortunately I have nothing I can share publicly. Let me try to explain a bit more.  The iFrame is hidden by default.  As well, there are elements IN the iFrame that are hidden as well.  On iFrame page load, I'm selectively showing these elements in the iFrame (iFrame is STILL hidden).  The iFrame remains hidden until a user event happens.  When the iFrame is shown, the inputs that were programmed to show, are not visible.  This is in FireFox only and when using jQuery's show() or fadeIn().

Comment: Can you make a fiddle or whatever that shows the problem? On re-reading, I realise that I have no idea where and how the `show()` calls are done. Inside the iframe, are the elements initially hidden (if so, how exactly) and then made visible in the onload? Or are they made visible from a call in the parent page? If so, when, before or after the iframe is made visible? Also, how is the iframe itself hidden and made visible exactly? Those kinds of details are important. Please create a small, self-contained, complete example that works the same way and also exhibits the same problem.

Comment: Instead of writing a comment, I'll update the ticket with new info.

Comment: Ah... yes. Like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ypx75/2/). Indeed the iframe doesn't get its onload called like it would when you'd load up it directly. Interesting. Sounds like a bug.

Comment: Thanks for having a look.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not an issue with the onload/onready not firing in Firefox. Because it does.

The issue is very specifically with the show() function not working in this particular situation - onload runs in the iframe while hidden.

Replace `$('...').show()` with `$('...').css('display','inline')` and it works fine.

See this fiddle combination page http://jsfiddle.net/xZdLx/4/ and iframe http://jsfiddle.net/L3Lxn/10/ in Firefox vs Chrome.

A very curious bug indeed, either a bug in jQuery or Firefox, and a good find.

**Workaround**

As you discovered yourself, `show()` will work if you first show the iframe and then force Firefox to reload the page by updating the iframe's `src`-attribute.